# Login from Mobile into Community

Tags: community, mobile

For Salesforce users, there is an app for iOS and Android to login from mobile. Is there a respective app for communities? Or users should login via safari/google chrome into their communities from their mobile devices ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Communities are accessible via browser, mobile or desktop.

If you want to convert the community into an app, there is a an offering by Salesforce called **[Mobile Publisher](https://youtu.be/ItDxOR99s7s)** which creates an app via clicks. It requires a license though.

To see how your current community will look like, you can install [Mobile Publisher playground](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=branded_apps_playground.htm)(Early release) from Android or iOS store and check it.

You can also create an app of your own which wraps your community in a Webview.

Comment: Thank you so much manjit5190!